# (Acessibilidade) Detectar dispositivos conectados ao computador ou mobile, e verificar funções ativas

Tags: ux, acessibilidade, navegação

### Detecção de dispositivos e Funções

Olá, **gostaria de saber se é possível programar o site para detectar se dispositivos**(periféricos) **específicos** (para acessibilidade) **estão conectados ao computador** e/ou funções específicas (como leitor de tela) estão ativas.

Percebi que **existe algumas dificuldades para deficientes** visuais, auditivos e motores **na hora de navegar na internet**. Então **eles utilizam aparelhos que ajudam na navegação**, **porem nem todos são compatíveis** com os sites, **pois a arquitetura do site foi feita sem pensar na acessibilidade**.

Um exemplo disso, que você mesmo pode testar, é tentar navegar usando apenas o teclado. **Apertando a tecla "Tab"** você percebe que **uma caixinha azul se move** entre os botões e links do site, navegando **da esquerda para a direita e de cima para baixo**. Essa tecla é muito utilizada por deficientes visuais para navegar pelo site, e **onde a caixinha azul estiver**, **o leitor de tela lerá**. Agora **imagine que ele queira ler um conteúdo** que só será encontrado **no meio do site** ou até mesmo no final dele. **Ele tem que apertar várias vezes o "Tab" para encontrar o conteúdo específico**.

Pensando nisso **queria saber se é possível identificar se existe algum aparelho específico conectado ao computador** (ou celular), **ou se existe alguma função ativada**, **para que fosse ativado ou alterado algo no site**, **facilitando a leitura e visualização** do site para deficientes visuais, auditivos e motores. Até mesmo para idosos que não tem mais a visão cem por cento, ou pessoas que tem dificuldades na leitura.